# How to check for common-related tab event

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need to trigger a function when the user choose a specific Related - common Tab. How can I catch that event (js).
A regular Tab can trigger a function if I configure it on the form but not related- common tab...

I'm using 365 - on premise and UCI

Thanks

Comment: This is a great question, I've never tried but I'll do some digging.  Is it just one tab in the related section or do you want to potentially do different things based on different related tables?  Could you make the related table a actual tab with just the associated view in the tab, set at the end of the form, so it is still out of the way?

Comment: Thanks,I want to trigger functions according to  related tab change - it can be alert or hide a button or something else.